# Android : How to detect app state in recent tasks?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

Im trying to detect app state in recent tasks through the following code, but i facing issue which is calling `onActivityStopped` immediately after `onActivityPaused`, is there any way i can just detect `onActivityPaused` state in recent tasks?

```
   ( context?.applicationContext as? Application)?.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(object :Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{

     override fun onActivityPaused(p0: Activity) {
       sendEvent("INACTIVE")
     }

     override fun onActivityStarted(p0: Activity) {
     }

     override fun onActivityDestroyed(p0: Activity) {
       sendEvent("CLOSED")
     }

     override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle) {

     }

     override fun onActivityStopped(p0: Activity) {
       sendEvent("BACKGROUND")
     }

     override fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity, p1: Bundle?) {
       sendEvent("ACTIVE")
     }

     override fun onActivityResumed(p0: Activity) {
       sendEvent("ACTIVE")

     }
   })
```

[ex : app in recent tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLX3U.png)

Answer (score 0):

What is the use case of detecting recent app state?  If you intend to check other apps state, you might be consider background service app.

Comment: Im building native module for detecting app state for both android and ios, in ios we have event(UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification) tell us when the app lose the focus in case the app goes from foreground to recent tasks but in android when the app goes from  foreground to recent tasks onActivityStopped immediately called after onActivityPaused, so in this case we can't know if the app just lose the focus or moved completely to background